# KQL extend to new column with summarize inside

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm trying to make a table with these columns

```
type | count
```

I tried this with no luck

```
exceptions 
| where timestamp > ago(144h) 
| extend 
    type = type, count = summarize count() by type
| limit 100
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Nir, please accept the answer if it helped (that's the StackOverflow way of saying Thank You :)). If you're still missing some info, please leave a comment, and I'll help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do this instead:

```
exceptions 
| where timestamp > ago(144h) 
| summarize count = count() by type
| limit 100
```

Explanation:

- You should use `extend` when you want to add new/replace columns to the result, for example, `extend day_of_month = dayofmonth(Timestamp)` - you'll remain with exactly the same record count in this case - see more info in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/extendoperator)
- You should use `summarize` when you want to summarize multiple records (so the record count after the `summarize` will usually be smaller than the original record count), like in your case - see more info in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/summarizeoperator)

By the way, instead of `144h` you can use `6d`, which is exactly the same, but is more natural to the human eye :)